# How to upload text file to FTP from Databricks notebook

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I tried to find a solution but nothing. I am new in this, so please help me if you know the solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your ask?  What do you mean by "upload text file to FTP from Databricks notebook"?

Comment: Yes. I have text file in ADLS and I want to write it (upload it) to FTP with code in Databricks notebook using pyspark

Answer (score 1):

```
Ok, I found a solution.

#copy file from ADLS to SFTP
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
from azure.datalake.store import core, lib, multithread
import pandas as pd

keyVaultName = "yourkeyvault"
#then you need to configure keyvault with ADLS

#set up authentification for ADLS
tenant_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = keyVaultName, key = "tenantId")
username = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = keyVaultName, key = "appRegID")
password = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = keyVaultName, key = "appRegSecret")
store_name = 'ADLSStoridge'
token = lib.auth(tenant_id = tenant_id, client_id = username, client_secret = password)
adl = core.AzureDLFileSystem(token, store_name=store_name)

#create secure connection with SFTP
ftp = FTP_TLS('ftp.xyz.com')
#add credentials
ftp.login(user='',passwd='') 
ftp.prot_p()
#set sftp directory path
ftp.cwd('folder path on FTP')

#load file
f = adl.open('adls path of your file')
#write to SFTP
ftp.storbinary('STOR myfile.csv', f)
```

Comment: Any options similar to stfp?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for accessing the files outside Databricks (using sftp software like WinSCP/FileZilla).
These are the steps I followed -

1. I downloaded the `awscli` using this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html in Databricks's cluster's terminal.
2. I ran this command in my Databricks notebook -

> !aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket S3-bucket-name --key
> path/to-s3/file.txt --acl bucket-owner-full-control

By doing these 2 steps I was able to access the file outside Databricks.

Answer (score -1):

In Databricks, you can access files stored in ADLS using any one of the method described below.
There are three ways of accessing Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2:

1. Mount an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 filesystem to DBFS using a service principal and OAuth 2.0.
2. Use a service principal directly.
3. Use the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 storage account access key directly.

**Steps to mount and access the files in your filesystem as if they were local files:**

To mount a Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 or a folder inside a container, use the following command:

**Syntax:**

```
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "<appId>",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": "<password>",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/token",
       "fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization": "true"}

dbutils.fs.mount(
source = "abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/folder1",
mount_point = "/mnt/flightdata",
extra_configs = configs)
```

**Example:**

[image]

After mounting the ADLS, you can access in your filesystem as if they were local files, for example:

```
df = spark.read.csv("/mnt/flightdata/flightdata.csv", header="true")
display(df)
```

**Example:**

[image]

**Reference:** [Databricks - Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thanks but this is not how to access ADLS it's how to upload file to FTP from databricks. I found a solution and I'll represent it in answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi @MilosTodosijevic, please do share your findings.This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.