# How to connect to SFTP server using Databricks without any JAR files?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, sftp, databricks

I tried using Python libraries such as ftplib but I was not able to establish any connection.

Comment: Please ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562744/how-to-upload-text-file-to-ftp-from-databricks-notebook

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload text file to FTP from Databricks notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562744/how-to-upload-text-file-to-ftp-from-databricks-notebook)