# How to connect and read files from Azure FTP folder using Python in Azure Databricks?

Tags: python, ftp, databricks, azure-databricks

I need to use Python in Azure Databricks to do the following:

1. Merge multiple text files stored in Azure FTP folder (**\VMAZR1\ABCDFiles**). Here, 'VMAZR1' is the server name and 'ABCDFiles' is the folder name
2. Store the merged file in the same location with new name

I can write the code to do the merging but I need assistance with connecting to Azure FTP folder and reading text file names only. Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640753/11289386). Just change the method of storing to retrieving, e.g., [**retrbinary**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrbinary), or **retrlines** as well as [**mlsd**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.mlsd) to get a list of file names.